# Is the an Expresso "like" addin for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) on a regular basis. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a similar tool used for building regular expressoins that's a Visual Studio addin? I like keeping everything in my IDE rather than having separate apps open.

I did find a [Regular Expression Explorer](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/08/free-regular-expression-addin-for.html), but it doesn't help with building the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Regex Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00)

Comment: Some not so good reviews, but upon testing, it appears to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to this [webpage](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) referencing many visual studio addins, and search for Regex,you will find some addins for that.